# Where is StateT in Cats?

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

I have in my sbt:

```
"org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.0.0-M1",
"org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.3.1",
"org.typelevel" %% "cats-free" % "2.0.0-M3"
```

But can't import StateT in code.

In what module is it?

It's referred to here http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/State.html

Comment: Fyi https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#what-imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StateT](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/d99325153b1b7b4d3aca1141935d6b67182a511d/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/package.scala#L55) is in `cats-core`

```
import cats.data.StateT
```

where

```
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % catsVersion
```